# how to log or print python elasticsearch-dsl query that gets invoked

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am using [elasticsearch-dsl](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py) for my python application to query elastic search.

To debug what query is actually getting generated by elasticsearch-dsl library, I am unable to log or print the final query that goes to elasticsearch.

For example, like to see the request body sent to elasticsearch like this :

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
           "query": "Dav*",
           "fields": ["name", "short_code"],
           "analyze_wildcard": true
        }
    }
}
```

Tried to bring the elasticsearch log level to TRACE. Even then, unable to see the queries that got executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at my blog post [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-logging-secrets), *"Slowlog settings at index level"* section. Basically, you can use slowlog to print in a separate log file Elasticsearch generates, the queries. I suggest using a very low threshold to be able to see **all** the queries.

For example, something like this, for a specific index:

```
PUT /test_index/_settings
{
  "index": {
    "search.slowlog.level": "trace",
    "search.slowlog.threshold.query.trace": "1ms"
  }
}
```

Or

```
PUT /_settings
{
  "index": {
    "search.slowlog.level": "trace",
    "search.slowlog.threshold.query.trace": "1ms"
  }
}
```

as a cluster-wide setting, for all the indices.

And the queries will be logged in your `/logs` location, a file called `[CLUSTER_NAME]_index_search_slowlog.log`.

Comment: Thanks Andrei for your answer. This satisfies my current debugging needs.,

Comment: Thanks - this helped. For others' reference, there are some additional ideas [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/issues/448)

Comment: I wonder how to turn the slow log off. "-1" does not work