# elasticsearch java client logback levels

Tags: java, logging, elasticsearch, groovy, logback

We have a Groovy application that uses the Elasticsearch java client library to query an Elasticsearch cluster. We'd like to see the actual queries the library is sending, for debugging purposes.

We are also using Logback and it would really be convenient to be able to tweak our logback config to have the Elasticsearch client output more detailed debugging logs on its own, without having to redeploy a code change.

I've been looking but have not found any documentation on this so far -- does anyone know if there is a logger that can be affected by logback that we can change? Something like `org.elasticsearch.client`?

Comment: I don't think there is one. Elasticsearch has a dedicated logging mechanism exactly for this purpose - [slowlogs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-slowlog.html). That's the official and recommended approach for monitoring the slow queries. Of course, you could lower the thresholds to very small values and basically see all the queries.

Comment: Ok, thanks @AndreiStefan

Comment: Also see @AndreiStefan's answer about how to set up slowlogs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410701/how-to-log-or-print-python-elasticsearch-dsl-query-that-gets-invoked/33410967#33410967