# Spring data aggregation query elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to make the below elasticsearch query to work with spring data. The intent is to return unique results for the field `"serviceName"`. Just like a `SELECT DISTINCT serviceName FROM table` would do comparing to a SQL database.

```json
{
  "aggregations": {
    "serviceNames": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "serviceName"
      }
    }
  },
  "size":0
}
```

I configured the field as a keyword and it made the query work perfectly in the `index_name/_search` api as per the response snippet below:

```json
"aggregations": {
        "serviceNames": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "service1",
                    "doc_count": 20
                },
                {
                    "key": "service2",
                    "doc_count": 8
                },
                {
                    "key": "service3",
                    "doc_count": 8
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

My problem is the same query doesn't work in Spring data when I try to run with a `StringQuery` I get the error below. I am guessing it uses a different api to run queries.

```
Cannot execute jest action , response code : 400 , error : {"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [aggregations]","line":2,"col":19}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [aggregations]","line":2,"col":19} , message : null
```

I have tried using the `SearchQuery` type to achieve the same results, no duplicates and no object loading, but I had no luck. The below sinnipet shows how I tried doing it.

```java
final TermsAggregationBuilder aggregation = AggregationBuilders
                .terms("serviceName")
                .field("serviceName")
                .size(1);
        SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withIndices("index_name")
                  .withQuery(matchAllQuery())
                  .addAggregation(aggregation)
                  .withSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
                  .withSourceFilter(new FetchSourceFilter(new String[] {"serviceName"}, new String[] {""}))
                  .withPageable(PageRequest.of(0, 10000))
                  .build();
```

Would someone know how to achieve no object loading and object property distinct aggregation on spring data?

I tried many things without success to print queries on spring data, but I could not, maybe because I am using the `com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate` implementation.
I got the query parts with the below:

```java
logger.info("query:" + searchQuery.getQuery());
logger.info("agregations:" + searchQuery.getAggregations());
logger.info("filter:" + searchQuery.getFilter());
logger.info("search type:" + searchQuery.getSearchType());
```

It prints:

```
query:{"match_all":{"boost":1.0}}
agregations:[{"serviceName":{"terms":{"field":"serviceName","size":1,"min_doc_count":1,"shard_min_doc_count":0,"show_term_doc_count_error":false,"order":[{"_count":"desc"},{"_key":"asc"}]}}}]
filter:null
search type:DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH
```

Comment: Can you print out the query that is being generated by Spring data?

Comment: Thanks for reading @Val I tried adding the queries the way I could, if you have any tip for adding queries it's welcome, I could not with `logging.level.org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core=DEBUG`

Comment: Does it also happen if you use the usual `ElasticsearchTemplate` class?

Comment: Can't do that because I am using elasticsearch 6.5, and spring data doesn't support it still. All other queries works fine. I think the key thing here is the `"size":0`. I have also tried running the query as a `StringQuery` it output me  that error, maybe I should edit the questions stating that.

Comment: Your Pageable makes it so that size will not be 0, I'm afraid. If you're only interested in aggregations, you should not return any hits.

Comment: Without pageable it returns me the default (10), if I set the term size to 0, it doesn't return anything. The `size:0` I mentioned is the one in the top level object of the query exemplified. which oddly works directly to elasticsearch, but not using spring data...

Comment: Ok, but setting 10000 in the Pageable is far from ideal

Comment: What happens if you remove the line `withQuery(...)`?

Comment: Spring Data ES 3.2.x supports up to ES 6.7.2, by the way

Comment: Agree, but the peageble was a test. If I remove the `withQuery(...)` I have the same results, many duplicated records.
About spring data 3.2.x, I am using boot, I had many issues configuring it, don't recall why, but I guess I would have the same issue?
Would you know why `StringQuery` won't work? that would solve it all.

Comment: It's very weird, I don't see why the query wouldn't work. Can you set [`index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.trace: 0ms`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/index-modules-slowlog.html#search-slow-log) so that we can see in the ES log what query gets executed ultimately?

Comment: I recalled, I am limited to the http endpoint as it's a cloud service. This is why I can't use the spring default implementation and why I can't set this setting.

Comment: Any tips on how can I write my own ad-hoc query? I searched around, no luck.

Comment: You can definitely change the slowlog settings via a REST endpoint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33410967/4604579 . Then Iif you're on ES Cloud, you might be able to see the logs in the ES Cloud Dashboard

Comment: Thanks @Val I figured out and responded to share knowledge, you enlighten the way even not responding.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out, maybe can help someone. The aggregation don't come with the query results, but in a result for it self and is not mapped to any object. The Objects results that comes apparently are samples of the query elasticsearch did to run your aggregation (not sure, maybe).
I ended up by creating a method which can do a simulation of what would be on the SQL `SELECT DISTINCT your_column FROM your_table`, but I think this will work only on keyword fields, they have a limitation of 256 characters if I am not wrong. I explained some lines in comments.
Thanks @Val since I was only able to figure it out when debugged into Jest code and check the generated request and raw response.

```java
public List<String> getDistinctField(String fieldName) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        final String distinctAggregationName = "distinct_field"; //name the aggregation

        final TermsAggregationBuilder aggregation = AggregationBuilders
                .terms(distinctAggregationName)
                .field(fieldName)
                .size(10000);//limits the number of aggregation list, mine can be huge, adjust yours

        SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withIndices("your_index")//maybe can be omitted
                .addAggregation(aggregation)
                .withSourceFilter(new FetchSourceFilter(new String[] { fieldName }, new String[] { "" }))//filter it to retrieve only the field we ar interested, probably we can take this out.
                .withPageable(PageRequest.of(0, 1))//can't be zero, and I don't want to load 10 results every time it runs, will always return one object since I found no "size":0 in query builder
                .build();
//had to use the JestResultsExtractor because com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate don't have an implementation for ResultsExtractor, if you use Spring defaults, you can probably use it.
    final JestResultsExtractor<SearchResult> extractor = new JestResultsExtractor<SearchResult>() {
                @Override
                public SearchResult extract(SearchResult searchResult) {
                    return searchResult;
                }
            };

            final SearchResult searchResult = ((JestElasticsearchTemplate) elasticsearchOperations).query(searchQuery,
                    extractor);
            final MetricAggregation aggregations = searchResult.getAggregations();
            final TermsAggregation termsAggregation = aggregations.getTermsAggregation(distinctAggregationName);//this is where your aggregation results are, in "buckets".
            result = termsAggregation.getBuckets().parallelStream().map(TermsAggregation.Entry::getKey)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // threat your error here.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;

    }
```